# VisualVM heap dump inconsistency with profiler

Tags: java, memory-leaks, profiler, visualvm

I am using VisualVM (Built in JDK1.6) to analyze my Java application looking for memory leaks.
I am using Heap Dump and the Profiler ( memory monitor ) both VisualVM features...
there is some inconsistency i cant understand, when dumping the heap i can see that there is a class which i wrote with about 8000 instance, when looking at the profiler classes & instances i cannot find the related class.. after a few heap dumps with period of time between i can see that the number of instances of the class is increasing and still in the profiler is gone.

I am wonder if this class is leaking, and why i cant see that on the profiler monitor?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VisualVM monitor is equivalent of heap dump. Profiler show instances that was created from start of profiling session.

But if you told that number of instances increasing they should go to profiler result. Strange. This work for me. Try other profiler. I prefer YourKit.

Comment: Yes. It gives much more futures - like inspections. It saves me a lot of time for tasks where you need for exaple find unclose FileOutputStream or memory leak.